# Thread 9: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0) firebase

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase

Running my app on simulator on iphone 7 & 8 runs this error:

[image]

It appears to be a problem with `FirebaseInstanceID` - Running the code on iphone xr works fine but any other device throws this error. No messages appear in the console either.

Edit:

`FirebaseApp.configure()` seems to be the code that crashes.

Comment: Questions like this are super hard to answer because there are so many things that could be causing it. What is the error? What is `self.session' and 'request'? 'handler' is unknown as well. Is your podfile updated? What version of Firebase? As you can see there's not enough information to address the question. We would really need to see very specific section of code that duplicates the issue. Please take a moment and review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Jay That's my only issue, given it works on some devices and not others its hard to pinpoint the exact code. The podfiles are updated and this is run before the appdelegate so I have no way of debunking from my code. Could be a simulator problem perhaps?

Comment: I would say it's not a simulator problem. However, running this before the appdelegte could be the issue because of the loading sequence and timing. Or perhaps it's how your podfile is configured. Or maybe even it... You can see, no way to answer without seeing your code to duplicate the issue.

Comment: All I know is, `FirebaseApp.configure()` triggers `NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [self.session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:handler];` to crash. What's twisted is the crash happening on some devices not others.

Comment: I am not seeing that sequence and because the question contains no code, no duplicatable MCV example, no error message and no further info, it will be impossible to assist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/3270 for which the fix will be published later this week with Firebase 6.4.0.

In the meantime, the workaround is to remove `FirebasePerformance` from the Podfile.

Comment: So... How in the world did you go from not knowing what the error was in the original question, nor the iOS version and with it only crashing on specific devices to linking that back to an issue with FirebasePerformance since that's not mentioned or shown in the question either? That was a huge leap. Well done. Is this a Firebase 6.3 issue only?

Comment: I recognized the backtrace. :) The crash can occur if any recent version of FirebasePerformance is linked, but it only happens with Xcode 11 on the iOS 13 beta.

Comment: Firebase 6.4.0 is now available via CocoaPods. Zip and Carthage distributions will be available soon.

Comment: Nailed it. Thanks so much @PaulBeusterien.